# A theorem of Szemeredi in Erdos's paper

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

In his [paper](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1980-03.pdf) "A survey of problems in combinatorial number theory", on page 110, Erdos writes:

> Graham conjectured: Let $1 \le a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_n$ be $n$ integers. Then $$ \max_{i,j} a_j/(a_i, a_j) \ge n. $$ Szemeredi proved this recently. The proof is not yet published.

I tried to find the proof among Szemeredi's publications, but failed. Can anyone provide me with any reference (or maybe the proof itself) to this theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [this](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa75/aa7511.pdf) paper : "On a conjecture of R. L. Graham" by R. Balasubramanian
and K. Soundararajan. They prove Graham's conjecture with the additional condition $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)=1$ a condition which can be obtained without the loss of generality. (So yes the link is indeed the proof of the conjecture.)

In the introduction, the authors say that Szemeredi gave a proof for $n=p$. So it may be the case in which there was some communication error(?) between Szemeredi and Erdos.

Cheers! :-)